# Is it possible to create .msi files that install files to non standard locations?

Tags: windows, installation, wix, windows-installer

I need to generate an .msi package to deploy some files on my computers. I can do this using a program called Deep Freeze. I provide the .msi and Deep Freeze puts it in my workstations.
I've been trying to create this .msi with the WiX sdk but I can't use my own folder path but as soon as I replace the APPLICATIONPATH with something else the compiler crashes without output.

Is it even possible or are .msi standards so strict that you can't just put files wherever you want?

Comment: WiX consists of several components. When you say "the compiler crashes", can you be more specific, e.g. do you use the toolkit from within Visual Studio (WiX can be a project type)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thank you guys for your attention, the information I needed was originally found [here](http://www.dalun.com/wix/04.25.2007.htm), quoted below:

> To achieve this, you can try these:
>
> - Don't worry about TARGETDIR
> - Create a public property (like MYAPPPATH, or INSTALLDIR) to set the new application installation location
> - Add a Directory node with Id="MYAPPPATH" and Name=".". Note: Name="." overrides the parent folder

```
<Property Id="MYAPPPATH"><![CDATA[c:\mydir\]]></Property>

<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
   <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder>
      <Directory Id="MYAPPPATH" Name=".">
         <Directory Id='MyDir' Name='TestProg' LongName='Test Program'>
            <Component Id='MyComponent'>
              ...
```